# Google Chrome extension development environment

Tags: google-chrome, testing, google-chrome-extension

As the title suggests I'm looking for a better Chrome extension development environment. I'm using Sublime Text 2 for my IDE, which is fine. The problem lies with testing the extension. Right now, when I need to test the code I've written I first have to launch Chrome with the –enable-easy-off-store-extension-install parameter. Then I need to package it through Chrome as an .crx file. Finally I have to drag and drop the file into Chrome and manually install it. Obviously this can get very time consuming very quickly.

I know I can test an extension as an unpacked extension, but this causes permission errors which is a problem since I need to perform CORs. Is there a better way to test extensions in Chrome?

Comment: What do you mean by COR ?

Comment: I mean't CORS, cross-origin resource sharing.